# flutter preserve the value in showModalBottomSheet when reopen

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `textField` in  `showModalBottomSheet`. What i want if user fill the value in `textField` and close the bottom sheet and reopen it the value must not be lost. The same value in `textField` must be shown. How can i preserve the value in modal bottom Sheet?

Answer (score 1):

1. create variable for value: `_value`
2. set new value for `_value` on onTextChanged()
3. When open bottom sheet, init value for textField

   `TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController(text: _value)`